# how do I upgrade pip on Mac?

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot upgrade pip on my Mac from the Terminal.

According to the documentation I have to type the command:
pip install -U pip

I get the error message in the Terminal:
pip: command not found

I have Mac OS 10.14.2, python 3.7.2 and pip 18.1.
I want to upgrade to pip 19.2.3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

upgrading pip as of 09/2020:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip==20.2.2
```

[Latest version here](https://pypi.org/project/pip), comment by DragonKnight

Comment: get the latest version of pip here
 https://pypi.org/project/pip/

Answer (score 20):

pip3 install --upgrade pip

---

this works for me!

Comment: So it did for the OP apparently as has been stated in their and one other answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
pip install --upgrade pip==19.2.3
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Saurav Rai, but I still have the problem. I get the error message: pip: command not found

Comment: @aurumpurum  happy to hear that you figured it out by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer that worked for me:
sudo pip3 install -U pip --ignore-installed pip

This installed pip version 19.2.3 correctly.

It was very hard to find the correct command on the internet...glad I can share it now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade to the latest pip version (as of this writing pip-21.2.4) and you are using mac, do the following:

Open your terminal, on your main folder and type:

```
$ pip3 -V
```

This will give you the version you have installed

Then type:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Or

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

The latest if you need to input your password

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks @outeh, but my problem still exists. I get the following error message: install: illegal option -- -
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...

Comment: Update: sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip3 gives the error message: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. But this command does not work. What can I do? I find it difficult to get good instructions to upgrade pip, there are a lot of recommendations, none of them work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I came on here to figure out the same thing but none of this things seemed to work. so I went back and looked how they were telling me to upgrade it but I still did not get it. So I just started trying things and next thing you know I seen the downloading lines and it told me that my pip was upgraded. what I used was (pip3 install -- upgrade pip). I hope this can help anyone else in need.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pip installed in the first place. Refer to  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ to install pip.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC with M1 :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

If you want to install specific version:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip==21.1.1
```

After pip == version_number should be entered

If you want to know more about pip commands:

```
pip3 help
```